# Issue with displaying python lists joined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing this 'bot' for an online chatroom, and i've made a game which utilizes an inventory, however i'm having a bit of trouble. Here's the code to return the inventory in a more "colorful" way which also displays how many of each item the user has:

```
def retInv(user):
inventory = getInv(str(user))
inv = []
for item in inventory:
    item = str(item)
    i = inventory.count(item)
    itemx = item.lower()
    item = item.title()
    if itemx in items.reagents:
        x = "<f x137FFF00='news gothic mt'><b>%s</b><f x13cccccc='news gothic mt'>(x%s)" % (item, str(i))
    elif itemx in items.rare_reagents:
        x = "<f x13BF5FFF='news gothic mt'><b>%s</b><f x13cccccc='news gothic mt'>(x%s)" % (item, str(i))
    elif itemx in items.ultra_rare_reagents:
        x = "<f x13FFD700='news gothic mt'><b>%s</b><f x13cccccc='news gothic mt'>(x%s)" % (item, str(i))
    elif itemx in items.misc:
        x = "<f x13FF9900='news gothic mt'><b>%s</b><f x13cccccc='news gothic mt'>(x%s)" % (item, str(i))
    elif itemx in items.enchanted:
        x = "<f x13FF4040='news gothic mt'><b>%s</b><f x13cccccc='news gothic mt'>(x%s)" % (item, str(i))

    else:
        x = "<f x1379CDCD='news gothic mt'><b>%s</b><f x13cccccc='news gothic mt'>(x%s)" % (item, str(i))
    if x in inv:
        pass
    else:
        inv.append(x)
return ', '.join(inv)
```

The problem with this is that this is what's being outputted:

```
 Dark Magic(x1), Stone(x1), Ectoplasm(x1), Hi(x1), Sledgehammer(x1), Lava Lily(x1), Ancient Scroll(x1), Fin(x1), Blossom(x5), Ruby(x1), Mushroom(x1), Trash(x1), Glass Vial(x1), Condom(x3), Iron(x1), Sunstone(x2), Paperclip(x3), Perfect Sapphire(x1), Leather(x1), Red Flower(x1), Spring(x2),
```

F00='news gothic mt'>Aether(x1), Fire(x1), Scissors(x1), Agave Nectar(x1), Perfect Citrine(x1), Golden Pearl(x1), Moss(x1), Perfect Peridot(x1) in your inventory.

The inventory gets split into two messages (the bot is run in a chatroom) and the second message returns part of the font tag "=F00='news gothic mt'>". I know for a fact that the chatroom allows messages with a length of 700 characters and I know for a fact that the output isn't more than 700 characters. My question is, why is the message being split and why is the font tag being displayed? Is there something i'm doing wrong/ something I can do to simplify the entire code? Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I put all those strings into a list and ```', '.join(inv)``` produces a single string with nothing amiss. You don't show how it is being used, maybe the problem is there.  Have you tried any diagnostic print statements where you call ```retInv```?

Comment: Does the 700 characters include the style codes?